# AMD R9 290 600watt enough?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, power-supply, amd-radeon

I have got an AMD R9 290, with a 600 watt power supply(Coolermaster GX 600 watt).
Now, when i am playing a game everything works fine, but when i am trying to mine bitcoins, my system crashes(no signal hdmi, all fans got to 100%).
I have got an I5 3570, and I have nothing overclocked(windows 8.1)
Is it possible that my video cart is asking more power then my power supply can give it?

Comment: I'm not into bitcoin mining but can say, as someone that's built computers for years, 600 watt is fine for a single R9 290 as it only uses 300 watts of power. So your rig should be fine. You'll need someone with bitcoin mining experience to chip in and offer help. Might wanna change title/tags to get one to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the power supply the GX-Lite 600W? Unless it's faulty it should be fine, since it should deliver [540W on the 12V rail](http://www.pcinpact.com/news/68092--gx-gx-lite-alimentation-500-w.htm).

While the R9 290's official TDP is 250W, reviews are placing it [unofficially at 300W](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7481/). Still, the PSU should cover that.

So yes, it could be the power supply, but only if it isn't functioning properly. Likewise, it could be some other part or even a software-related issue. Without some more info (errors logs or something), or testing by trying alternate hardware, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: Beat me to it! Good point about the dodgy software possibility.

Answer (score 0):

From the system requirements from [several](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/R92904GD5/#specifications) [different](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4821#sp) [manufacturers](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?cid=1&gid=3&sgid=1227&pid=2044&psn=&lid=1&leg=0), it looks like you could need anywhere from a 600W up to 750W power supply for this card.

The ASUS product page suggests that the card will use 300W of power, which is obviously 50% of your total power available. I would guess that while gaming is fine if it's not completely stressing the card 100% of the time, mining Bitcoins is going to draw too much power and result in crashes like you are experiences.